# jQuery change title dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating just a static html website that got a little large so I started breaking it up into templates. I am including a header.php and have run into a problem with the title. I want to get the name of the page, i.e. about.php and output that in the title `<title>Company name - About</title>`

I have gotten this working like so:

```
var name = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
var title = name.slice(0, -4);
var finalTitle = "Company-" + title;
$(document).attr("title", finalTitle);
```

works perfect except for index where it doesn't display the name for obvious reasons. I tried writing an if statement along the lines of:

```
var name;
if (location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0] === ""){
   name = "Home";
} else {
   name = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
}
```

Now I am not too sure why this isn't working.

Comment: If you are putting the header in PHP, why not dynamically set the title in PHP rather than in javascript?  Your javascript approach is going to be bad from an SEO perspective.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry meant to have "" there instead of 0

Comment: @MikeBrant trying to find examples and google keeps giving wordpress related results only

Comment: It is as simple as `<title><?php echo $your_title_string; ?></title>`  Of course this is assuming that you have logic to determine your title string (could be an array lookup if you wanted to "hard code" the titles or could dymanically be determined from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which is like what you are trying to do with javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after consultation that can be followed in the comments I went the PHP route with this. This is not going to help anyone looking for a javascript answer but here is what I am using that now works:

```
<?php 
  $title = ucwords(str_replace(array("-","/"),array(" "," - "),substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1))); 
  $afterTitle = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $title);
  $final;
  if ($afterTitle == "Company - "){
      $final = "Company - Home";
  } else {
      $final = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $title);
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to do it is:

```
/*
 * This gets the path as an array and tried to get the last subdirectory, 
 * if isn't return undefined in wich case will set the title to 'Home';
 */
var title = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g,'').split('/').pop() || 'Home';

//This part assign the title capitalizing it.
$('title').html(title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title.slice(1))
```

For anyone who wants to add this functionality here is a code that adds class names to the html tag for each subdirectory and an id for the last part of the url. This could be changed o simple used to set the title like the original question asks.

```
// Gets the path subdirectories as an array and use the last as the id.
var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g,'').split('/'), 
    id = path.pop() || 'index';

// Adds the classes and id to the html tag
$('html').attr("class", path.join(' '))
    .attr('id', id);

//Assign the title capitalizing the id
$('title').html(id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + id.slice(1))
```

The main goal of this script is so you can add styles to every page usin its id like head.js doit.